# Running multiple commands in background without over lapping (PHP & Ubuntu)

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu, background, asynchronous

Why hello there! I appreciate any potential answers presented. 
Basically, I need two shell commands to run in the background so my website user doesn't need to wait until the process has been completed to further navigate the website. However these two commands cannot run at the same time as they will affect eachother. The Second one NEEDS to run after the first. The important part of my code can be found below!

```
shell_exec("sudo " . $command . ">> /dev/null &1");
shell_exec("sudo make all install >> /dev/null &1");
```

Is there any way of letting them run asynchronously?

Thanks!

Comment: [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), see Lists section

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably better of with some queuing solution ie. putting the shell execution jobs in a queue and return quickly to the user and in a daemon like process in a single thread read and execute the queued jobs.
A quite good and php friendly queue solution is beanstalk with the pheanstalk php library